# How to save Data factory stored procedure output

Tags: azure-data-factory

Whenever I execute a stored procedure in the ADFv2, it gives me an output as

```
{
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (Australia Southeast)",
    "executionDuration": 34 
}
```

even though I have set 2 variables as output in the procedure. Is there any way to map the output of the stored procedure in the ADFv2? Till now I can map the output of all the other activities but not of Stored procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lookup activity to get the result.
Please reference this post. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/82e84ec4-fc40-4bd3-b6d5-b742f3cd1a33/adf-v2-how-to-check-if-stored-procedure-output-is-empty?forum=AzureDataFactory

*Update by Gagan*:
Instead of getting the output of SP (which is not possible in ADFv2 right now), I stored the output in the table and then apply lookup-foreach to the table to get the value.

Comment: The link says that 'reference your stored procedure as the source dataset of the lookup activity'. As far as I know I need to have a dataset already in the ADFv2 to use it in the lookup. How should I edit that field to take the output of the stored procedure? And I dont want to stored the result of the proc in the table. So that is out of the question.

Comment: Ok. I think MSDN answer is assume that the stored procedure is used as sink of a copy activity, instead of a stored procedure activity. Could you share a little more about your scenario? If you don’t want store the result, why do you need the output?

Comment: I am doing incremental load in ADFv2 and hence I have to update one column of the table and then retrieve datetime value from the watermark column of the table which would be my output of the proc which I will use thereon. This is happening in the stored procedure.

Comment: I think you have to store that value. There is a step by step tutorial.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal

Comment: So essentially, ADF does not provide any functionality in stored proc activity to output the values. One has to seperately do something or all together change the logic.

Comment: Currently, yes.

Comment: This is a tool with so much potential and yet time and time again I get caught out by missing functionality like this.

Comment: It _is_ possible to get the output of a stored procedure from a lookup activity. If you define column aliases for output inside the stored procedure, you can reference them in subsequent steps as follows: @{activity('My_Lookup_Activity').output.firstRow.OutputColumn1}, where OutputColumn1 is the aliased column. Please refer to the following article for more details:https://dataconcepts.blog/2017/11/23/azure-data-factory-v2-calling-stored-procedures-with-output-parameters/

Answer (score 4):

Stored procedure call in Data factory (v2) does not capture the result data set. So you cannot use the stored procedure activity to get the result data set and refer it in next activities.
Workaround is to use lookup activity to call exact same stored procedure as lookup will get you the result data set from stored procedure. Replace your Stored procedure activity with lookup and it will work.

Comment: Make sure to add a SELECT in the Stored Procedure (instead or alongside the output parameter). This makes the it available for the Lookup Activity. [Details](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2020/12/adf-snack-use-stored-procedure-output.html) and [upvote](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/36538312-allow-stored-procedure-output-parameters)