# How to get date String output from stored procedure in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I have a stored procedure in Azure SQL DB that returns 2 output parameters, `startDate` and `endDate` based on an input date string.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_DEDUCE_START_DATE_END_DATE
    @inputDateTimeString NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    @startDate NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL OUT,
    @endDate NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL OUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- exact logic omitted as to demonstrate the 2 outputs date string only
    SELECT 
        @inputDateTime AS inputDateTime, 
        @startDate AS startDate, @endDate AS endDate

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

What I am looking for: a complete end-to-end solution to:

1. get the 2 output date strings `startDate`, `endDate` from the stored procedure
2. store the 2 date strings to 2 pipeline variables `START_DATE`, `END_DATE` (as I have other processing logic to affect the pipeline variables)
3. feed the 2 pipeline variables to downstream dataflow(s) as parameters

What I have tried/viewed:

1. The [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/82e84ec4-fc40-4bd3-b6d5-b742f3cd1a33/adf-v2-how-to-check-if-stored-procedure-output-is-empty?forum=AzureDataFactory) in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51344947/14732669) - It's close, but not a complete answer as the syntax seems incomplete
2. This [link](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2020/12/adf-snack-use-stored-procedure-output.html) mentioned that Stored Procedure activity cannot be used to access the SP outputs; will need lookup activity instead

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Why would you have dates stored as `nvarchar(max)`, keep them in their proper types `date` or `datetime`

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your advice. The stored procedure is actually a legacy development product that is used for implementing some non-trivial business logic. Unfortunately the stored procedure is adopted by some other production system so that the stored procedure is unlikely to be modified. However I will keep your naming convention advice in mind and avoid that next time :)

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for your advice. As replied in another comment, the stored procedure is some legacy development product. My guess is that they are kept as narchar/string for some system integrations but I think I will leave out from commenting whether that is a good practice as it is irrelevant to the ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share my final end-to-end working solution.

Here is a simplified overview of my final pipelines:
[image]
A lookup activity to trigger the SP; followed by setting 2 variables, then feed to downstream dataflow.

**The syntax of parameters supplied to the SP:**
[image]
You have to check `Treat as null` option for the 2 outputs. Then supply the date string to SP.

**To read the SP outputs and set the variables(only used START_DATE here as example since END_DATE is identical):**
[image]

Put in `@activity('SP_DEDUCE_START_DATE_END_DATE').output.firstRow.startdate`

**To feed the 2 variables to downstream dataflow:**
[image]

Put in `@variables('START_DATE')` in pipeline expression.